# Use interface property as type

Tags: typescript

I have a external library which exports:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { BsPrefixComponent } from './helpers';

export interface ListGroupItemProps {
  action?: boolean;
  active?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant?:
    | 'primary'
    | 'secondary'
    | 'success'
    | 'danger'
    | 'warning'
    | 'info'
    | 'dark'
    | 'light';
}

declare class ListGroupItem<
  As extends React.ReactType = 'a'
> extends BsPrefixComponent<As, ListGroupItemProps> {}

export default ListGroupItem;
```

How can I use the variant as a type in my own interface? I am trying to do something like:

```
import ListGroupItemProps from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';

export interface Message {
    from?: string;
    content?: string;
    variant?: ListGroupItemProps.variant;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [index type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
import { ListGroupItemProps } from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';

export interface Message {
    from?: string;
    content?: string;
    variant?: ListGroupItemProps['variant'];
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include the file, the above gives me `Property 'variant' does not exist on type 'ListGroup<"div">'`

Comment: @Daniell I don't see your edit, the code should work. I think your import syntax was wrong, the default export was `ListGroupItem` to import the interface you need to use `import { ListGroupItemProps } from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';`